# Create a dictionary from the common property values of a List<Object>

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

Let's say we have a list of `_2DLine` objects.

```
public class _2DLine
{
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }
}

var L1 = new _2DLine { X1 = 0, Y1 = 0, X2 = 100, Y2 = 100 };
var L2 = new _2DLine { X1 = 50, Y1 = 50, X2 = 200, Y2 = 200 };
var L3 = new _2DLine { X1 = 0, Y1 = 0, X2 = 200, Y2 = 200};
var L4 = new _2DLine { X1 = 100, Y1 = 100, X2 = 50, Y2 = 50};

var MyLines = new List<_2DLine>
{
    L1,
    L2,
    L3,
    L4
}
```

As you can see, some of the lines have points in common. **How can we extract all the points from this list into a dictionary so that for a specific `_2DPoint(X,Y)` we will have a list of the lines entering or exiting that point.**

```
var MyPoints = new Dictionary<_2DPoint, List<_2DLine>>();

public class _2DPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

The final result would be like this:

```
  Key              |    Value
-----------------------------------
_2DPoint(0,0)      |   { L1, L3 }
_2DPoint(100,100)  |   { L1, L4 }
_2DPoint(50,50)    |   { L2, L4 }
_2DPoint(200,200)  |   { L2, L3 }
```

Comment: That seems like a straightforward requirement. What is blocking you from the solution? I see no question here.

Comment: @user414076 I'm confused how to create that dictionary.

Comment: @Vahid: Specify which step of that process is difficult. Creating a dictionary? Specifying the contents of a dictionary? Filtering the input set to determine what goes into the dictionary?

Comment: Is it the code that's giving you a problem, or is it the algorithm? If I'm left to infer, I'm thinking you do not have a good algorithm in mind. But maybe it's the code. I don't know, because you haven't asked a question.

Comment: @Guvante (1) Go through `X1,Y1,X2,Y2` of all the lines in the `MyLines list. (2) Then find the lines that enter or exit each of these points (3) Create the dictionary

Comment: @Vahid: I am asking you where you are having difficulty, not what the problem description is. I understand what you are trying to do, I am trying to figure out what help you need to get there. Giving you a full solution doesn't make sense when you just need a way of avoiding passing through the list twice or some such issue.

Comment: I was having problem with creating the dictionary which involved the above-mentioned steps. The solution Sergey gave was the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Vahid I updated answer with some comments on query and suggestions on improving your code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project lines to flattened sequence of points and lines, then group sequence by points (I use anonymous types, because they have implemented Equals and GetHashCode) and create dictionary:

```
var result = MyLines.SelectMany(l => new[] { 
                                   new { X = l.X1, Y = l.Y1 },
                                   new { X = l.X2, Y = l.Y2 }
                                }, (l,p) => new { Point = p, Line = l })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.Point)
                   .ToDictionary(g => new _2DPoint { X = g.Key.X, Y = g.Key.Y },
                                 g => g.Select(x => x.Line).ToList());
```

---

Suggestion - use your points as start and end of lines, instead having four coordinates. Also improve naming. Don't start class names from underscore, use camelCase names for local variables. E.g.

```
public class Line
{
    public Line(double startX, double startY, double endX, double endY)
        : this(new Point(startX, startY), new Point(endX, endY))
    {
    }

    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }
    public Point Start { get; private set; }
    public Point End { get; private set; }
}
```

I would also create point as value object and override Equals and GetHashCode methods to compare points by their values:

```
public class Point
{
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Point other = obj as Point;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {            
        return X.GetHashCode() * 19 + Y.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now creating list of lines looks like:

```
var lines = new List<Line> {
    new Line(0, 0, 100, 100),
    new Line(50, 50, 200, 200),
    new Line(0, 0, 200, 200),
    new Line(100, 100, 50, 50)
};
```

And points dictionary creation:

```
var points = lines.SelectMany(l => new[] { l.Start, l.End },
                              (l, p) => new { Line = l, Point = p })
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Point)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.Line).ToList());
```

Comment: Just wow Sergey, exactly the solution I wanted. There are some really brilliant guys here in SO.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update, the `Line` did interfere with `Line` in WPF that is the reason I chose `_2DLine`. for the other classes I'm using camelCase as you said.